# Delphi - Outlook OLE - CurrentUser overrides SendUsingAccount

Tags: delphi, automation, outlook, ole, office-automation

I am trying to use Outlook to send emails from a specific account.

Users have two or more accounts in their Outlook app and automation needs to use a specific account to send emails from.

To achieve this I used mailItem.SendUsingAccount property as intended per [OLE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount).

Example below.

The problem is when generated email is displayed - FROM field uses CurrentUser account not the one set by SendUsingAccount property.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

```
procedure TOutlookOLE.AssignSenderFromAccounts(const _MailFromEmail: string);
var
  i: integer;
  NewSender: OleVariant;
  sendermail: string;

  report: string;
begin
  if Connected then
  begin
    i := OutlookAppObject.Session.Accounts.Count;

    // Cycle through all accounts to identify correct one
    for I := 1 to OutlookAppObject.Session.Accounts.Count do
    begin

      NewSender  := OutlookAppObject.Session.Accounts.Item(i);
      sendermail := VarToStr(NewSender.SmtpAddress);

      // Match accounts based on email address
      if NOT VarIsNull(NewSender) AND SameText(sendermail, _MailFromEmail) then
      begin

        // Match FOUND and set to mail Item ...
        // ... but when Displayed THIS IS NOT THE CASE
        if MailCreated then
              OutlookMailItem.SendUsingAccount := NewSender
        else  raise Exception.Create('Outlook OLE Exception: Mail object not created.');
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else raise Exception.Create('Outlook OLE Exception: Outlook not connected.');
end;
```

**Updated  WORKING method after Dmitri's reply**

```
procedure TOutlookOLE.AssignSenderFromAccounts(const _MailFromEmail: string);

  const PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F';

var
  i: integer;
  NewSender: OleVariant;
  sendermail: string;

  report: string;
begin
  if Connected then
  begin
    i := OutlookAppObject.Session.Accounts.Count;

    for I := 1 to OutlookAppObject.Session.Accounts.Count do
    begin
      NewSender  := OutlookAppObject.Session.Accounts.Item(i);
      sendermail := VarToStr(NewSender.SmtpAddress);

      if NOT VarIsNull(NewSender) AND SameText(sendermail, _MailFromEmail) then
      begin
        if MailCreated then
        begin
          OutlookMailItem.SendUsingAccount := NewSender;

          OutlookMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
            PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            WideString(_MailFromEmail));
        end
        else  raise Exception.Create('Outlook OLE Exception: Mail object not created.');

        break;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else raise Exception.Create('Outlook OLE Exception: Outlook not connected.');
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known Outlook issue - try to also update the `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS` MAPI property:

```
    OutlookMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty('http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F', WideString(_MailFromEmail));
```

Comment: Since my votes aren't accepted yet, I'll say it in a comment. This works! I'll update the issue. Thank you!!

Comment: @Andrej - you can mark the post as an answer. Thanks!